# Check if Android Device is GearVR Compatible

Tags: android, mobile-devices

I am looking to check and see if an android device is GearVR compatibility for cross platform integrations, is there a way to check for this?

Answer (score 1):

The current way I am doing this is by checking its model because of the  limited devices compatible currently with the GearVR: Note 4/5, Samsung S6/S6edge/S6edge+.

https://gist.github.com/apollow/5b1bfc3b43d0399fa23a